# Can't pull a JSON from Tumblr on Python (GET returns HTTP instead)

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests

I'm attempting to pull a JSON from my Tumblr page such that I can display an image within a Jupyter notebook globally rather than just pasting locally saved images. Ideally, I'd GET the JSON, extract the png URL and then use IOBytes and PIL to display the image.

However, when I send a get request to the server:

```
import json
import requests
url = 'https://www.tumblr.com/blog/ims4jupyter'
r = requests.get(url, headers={'accept': 'application/json'})
print(r.json())
```

I get a JSONDecodeError. Typing,

```
r.content
```

into the terminal returns a HTTP formatted webpage. I think this means that Tumblr refuses to return JSON, but other websites (such as YouTube, for example) won't return JSON either.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this question was that the website I was trying to request JSON from did not accept those requests. If you copy my code, but instead use https://api.my-ip.io/ip.json (as an example), the original code will run.